# SEO Does my ranking is affected if I put links in the content to another website of my own?

Tags: seo, multiple-domains, sitelinks

I have a network of ecommerce sites.. All of them sell the same thing but I made one specific for a city. like for NY  cars-new-york-1.whatever 
and have the main one for USA: cars-usa-1.whatever

I want to put all selling cars in the USA site and links in the content of cars-new-york-1.whatever to cars-usa.whatever where the actual car specification is.

Will that affect my seo in cars-new-york-1.whatever? 
or Google understand that the other one is part of my network (it even have the same cms behind it)

Should I only add like a banner in the NY site to USA site and nothing more not to loose ranking?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to do localization using `usa.topleveldomain.com` as your main site but with a more local `ny-usa.topleveldomain.com`, ultimiatly linking back to `usa.topleveldomain.com`.

If not tagged properly, Google could see this is a duplication of content and therefore downgrade both domains.

I suggest you look into `Rel=Canonical` tags. Some good documentation can be [found here](https://moz.com/blog/cross-domain-rel-canonical-seo-value-cross-posted-content).